# HTA vbscript dropdown that filters other dropdowns

Tags: html, windows, vbscript, hta

I fairly new to creating HTA's, how can I create a dropdown that will filter the results for other dropdowns?   I have a database with sitename and state and what I would like is to populate the site dropdown after state is selected with just those records where the state that was selected matches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a very simple HTA which populates one dropdown based on the selection from another.  Should be easy to adapt to read from your database.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <HTA:APPLICATION
      APPLICATIONNAME="Test"
      ID="Test"
      VERSION="1.0"/>
</head>

<script language="VBScript">

    Sub Window_OnLoad
        Populatedropdown1
    End Sub

    Sub Populatedropdown1
            For i = 0 To 5
                Set opt = document.createElement("option")
                opt.Value = i
                opt.Text = "Option " & CStr(i)
                dropdown1.add opt
            Next    
    End Sub

    Sub Populatedropdown2
            For Each opt in dropdown2.Options
                opt.RemoveNode
            Next 
            For i = dropdown1.value To 10
                Set opt = document.createElement("option")
                opt.Value = i
                opt.Text = "Option " & CStr(i)
                dropdown2.add opt
            Next    
    End Sub
</script>

<body bgcolor="white">

    <p>Select 1: <select name="dropdown1" id="dropdown1" onchange="Populatedropdown2"></select></p>
    <p>Select 2: <select name="dropdown2" id="dropdown2" ></select></p>

</body></html>
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

What if my first dropdown list will list all sub_folder in a parent folder, when i pick up one sub-folder from 1st dropdown, it will generate the secend dropdown list which will list all sub folder in there and so on? How to do this?

---

```
<HEAD>
  <TITLE>K Drive Program Structure</TITLE>
  <HTA:APPLICATION ID="Eeee" 
    APPLICATIONNAME="C Drive " 
    BORDER="Dialog"
    CAPTION="Yes"
    SCROLL="NO"
    SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"
    SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
    SYSMENU="Yes"
    WINDOWSTATE="maximize">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">

Sub UpdateList
  For Each opt In list.Options
   opt.RemoveNode
  Next

  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\WORK").SubFolders
    Set opt = document.createElement("OPTION")
    opt.Text  = f.Name
    opt.Value = f.Path
    list.Add(opt)
  Next
End Sub

Sub EnumSubFolders
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  For Each opt In list.options
    If opt.selected Then
      Set sf = fso.GetFolder(opt.value).SubFolders

      Exit For
    End If
  Next
End Sub
</SCRIPT>

<H2>K Drive Structure</H2>
<P>CUSTOMER NAME
<select id="list" name="list" onkeydown="UpdateList" onChange="EnumSubFolders"></select><P>




<BR>
<BR>
<Input Type = "Button" Name = "btn01" VALUE = "SUBMIT">
<Input Type = "Button" Name = "btn02" VALUE = "CLOSE">
<BR>
<BR>

</BODY>
```